# Why can we set LLM's input and output to be the same when fine tuning on text generation task?

Tags: nlp, large-language-model, gpt-2, fine-tuning, text-generation

I'm trying to fine tune my GPT-2 model for song lyrics text generation, and I have a couple of song lyrics on hand. However, I'm confused about how to fine tune GPT-2 model that doesn't have standard input and outputs format. The reason is that I want my fine tuned GPT-2 to generate anything in a lyric style, and I don't know what should be the expected output given the song lyrics datasets on hand.

After searching related articles online, I found a really confusing solution on [How to Fine-Tune GPT-2 for Text Generation](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fine-tune-gpt-2-for-text-generation-ae2ea53bc272) using the following training method:

```
outputs = model(input_tensor, labels=input_tensor)
loss = outputs[0]
loss.backward()
```

From my understanding, the first parameter is the input text of the model, while the second parameter `labels` is usually the expected output of the model. If we just set it to be the same, are we actually training a repeater that always repeats the input text? If so, how could we expect that our fine tuned model can speak everything in a lyric style?

(Additional Question during my trial and error): Intuitively, I thought I should split each song into 2 halfs. Then I use first half as inputs to my GPT-2 model, and set the expected output to be the second half. But after some experiments I found my fine-tuned GPT-2 kept repeating words like "the" in down-stream tasks. I'm curious about the reason why I failed here.

Answer (score 0):

GPT-2 is designed to predict the next token in a sequence based on the preceding tokens. For instance, given the phrase "I love", it might predict "you".

**1. Why Using `input_tensor` for both Input and Labels**

The confusion often arises when seeing `input_tensor` used for both input and labels. This is due to the **Masking** mechanism inherent in GPT-2.

Unlike BERT, where specific tokens are masked and the model predicts them, GPT-2's masking is about controlling which tokens are visible during each prediction step. For a sequence like "I love music", the model predicts:

1. `"I"` -> `"love"`
2. `"I love"` -> `"music"`

This is achieved through internal masking. The model doesn't see future tokens, ensuring genuine next-token prediction based on the given context. So, using `input_tensor` for both input and labels doesn't make the model a mere repeater. It's training the model to predict subsequent tokens based on prior context.

**2. Splitting Songs in Half**

Manually splitting song lyrics isn't ideal. GPT-2's design inherently predicts the next token for each position in the sequence. Splitting songs might bias the model towards the latter parts, potentially limiting its learning.

**3. A Better Approach**

Consider using Descriptive Prompts:

- Structure your dataset with prompts describing the song's style or theme, followed by the corresponding lyrics. For instance:

  Input: `"A melancholic ballad about lost love in winter."`

  Output: `"Snowflakes fall, my heart calls, for the love lost in winter's thrall..."`

This approach can guide the model more effectively in generating lyrics in the desired style.

Comment: Thank you very much @padeoe ! But I'm still a little bit confused about what you said about masking. I do know that the output tokens are generated one-by-one, but assume that the model is predicting the first word as output, at that moment the model should be able to see full `input_tensor` as "prior context" right? And the model may notice that the desired word to predict is just in the `input_tensor` and perform as repeater. Could you please tell me where I made the mistake? Thanks for your patience.